# How can I always round a float number up?

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding, ceil

I have a `float` number of `1.000001f`

I want to round it up to the next integer. In this case to `2`.

How can I do that?

I tried `Math.Floor`, `Math.Ceiling`, `Math.Round`. Nothing works.

Comment: Ceiling would seem to be what you want; in what way did it "not work"?

Comment: I tried that before. Funny. Now it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't have an issue with this using [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
float precise = 1.000001f;

var roundedUp = (int)Math.Ceiling(precise); // 2: System.Int32
```

**note** - `roundedUp` will be of type `System.Double` without the `(int)` cast

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i1jNda) - demo